# How to copy part of one vector to another in c++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, range

I have a matirx sotred in a vector in row major order. For example:

```
1 5 9 13 2 6 10 14 3 7 11 15 4 8 12 16
```

I have a function

```
void transformatrix( vector<uint32> *vector_a)
```

that performs some modifications to a matrix. I need to pass part of a vector to that function. For example I need to pass

```
2 6 10 14
```

What I'm thinking about is to create a copy of a vector, pass it to a function:

```
vector<int> v2(v.begin() + x, v.begin() + x + y);
```

But it would be better to create another vector that will be just a pointer to original vector as I always access elements sequentially.

Is there any way how to create another vector without coping data?

Comment: _"Is there any way how to create another vector without coping data?"_ **No.**

Comment: You could have a vector of iterators but since your data is just `int`s I would copy them

Comment: A part of a vector, a.k.a. a *range*, is *a pair of iterators*.

Comment: Learn how to use iterators.

Comment: You want your original vector to stay not edited after calling that function ?

Comment: @Humam Helfawi - no I want to have original vector modified

Comment: You may want to look into [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will help:

```
template <typename T> void your_function(T it_beg,T it_end){
    //do what ever you want
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    your_function(v.begin()+x,v.begin()+x+y);
}
```

---

Use Case:

```
//Multiply all element by 2
template <typename T> void your_function(T it_beg,T it_end){
    for(auto it=it_beg;it!=it_end;++it){
        *it*=2;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

After the OP provided this delcartion:

```
void transformatrix( vector<uint32> *vector_a)
```

The only way to solve it without send the vector without copying is as follow:

*Note: This is a horrible idea. Do **NOT** use it. It is not thread safe. It is bad and anyone reviews your code will hate you more that you can imagine.*

```
int main(){
    std::vector<int> v{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
    v.emplace_back(x);
    v.emplace_back(y);
    transformatrix(&v);
    v.pop_back();
    v.pop_back();
}
```

Inside `transformatrix`:

```
void transformatrix( vector<uint32> *vector_a){
    auto beg_index=vector_a[vector_a.size()-2];
    auto end_index=vector_a[vector_a.size()-2]+vector_a[vector_a.size()-1];
    //Your original code here with respect that you indexes now from beg_index->end_index
}
```

Again this is broken solution but it is the only way to do it regarding to your constraints. Note that this will not fully  work for x64 platform because the data type is 32 and I use it for indexing too. So you can only benefit from 32 bit indexing on 64 platform

Comment: Can you change it?

Comment: Please edit your question with this information : What is the function deceleration?... can you change it? ... we can not know anything you did not provide:)

Comment: I can change it but I have several such functions :( That's why It would be better to pass a vector.

Comment: No. Since you can change it you should change it to the better. However, if you insist to stay with that declaration, could you show it to us?

Comment: @user1209304 If you want to pass sub-ranges to the function, then you don't want to pass a full vector into the function. Choose the parameter types accordingly. If you have several functions that should accept sub-ranges, then all those functions should take iterators, not vectors.

Comment: @user1209304 See my edit but do not use it please. Change your function. Read about iterator and how they are beautiful

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give it a try. I don't need a thread safe solution as I always modify different part of a vector. I never modify the same place 2 times. May I ask about iterator? Will it be the same fast as if I work with vector directly? Performance is very important.

Comment: @user1209304 Iterator is just a wrapper around pointers. It is the fastest way. Iterators are used among the standard library implementation. So YES they are the fastest way.

Answer (score 1):

You can have iterators that hold these locations (which may get invalidated).

```
vector<int>::const_iterator start = v.begin() + x;
vector<int>::const_iterator till =  v.begin() + x + y;
```

It doesn't create another `vector` but the positions (and the actual values) may become invalid on any `vector` operation.